# how to read a xpdl file with csharp

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying of read a XPDL file but not know how to read the nodes and child nodes with code .net

Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://www.wfmc.org/2008/XPDL2.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="ff23521d-41c3-4f2b-9ef4-2656d08d39a4" Name="Sample" OnlyOneProcess="false">
        <WorkflowProcesses>
            <WorkflowProcess Id="ad724ad9-b2f2-4be3-bced-5d6864b06e5a" Name="P">
                <Activities>
                    <Activity Id="d6ccf57c-b961-48ce-8b3f-5e98c2d2c9ef" Name="S">
                        <Description />
                        <Event>
                            <StartEvent Trigger="None" />
                        </Event>
                        <Documentation />
                        <ExtendedAttributes />                
                    </Activity>
                </Activities>
                <ExtendedAttributes />
            </WorkflowProcess>
        </WorkflowProcesses>
        <ExtendedAttributes />
    </Package>
```

I need read the node WorkflowProcess and the nodes child

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: check these examples to get an idea  - `http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm` and `http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/167ad2/read-xml-file-using-xml-reader-in-C-Sharp/`

Comment: What have you done for research so far? Have you looked into the XmlReader class?

Comment: the second link this broken :(

Comment: I've been usundo XDocuement, but I no manage to read nodes